# how to loop iteratively through 2 dictionaries and create another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have one list with 500000 records each stored as a dictionary. Essentially a list of dictionaries. Each record has a 'code' and 'count'. There could be multiple records with the same 'code'.

I have a dictionary with over 100000 records with the 'code' as a key but a 'zip' as a value. 'code' here is unique and multiple 'code' could have the same 'zip'

I want to find out the 'count' corresponding to each 'zip' and store them in another dictionary with 'zip' as key and 'count' as the value.

I am writing a nested for loop but it is taking too long.

```
zip_count = {}
for key1, val1 in dict1.items(): # dictionary with code,zip

    for key2, val2 in list1: # this is the list of dictionaries
        if key2 == key1:  # looking for a match of the code
           if val1 in zip_count:
              zip_count[val1] = zip_count[val1] + val2
           else:
              zip_count[val1] = val2
```

This is a cumbersome procedure given the size of the datasets.

Can someone please help?  Here is the input and same output:

```
List1 = 

[{'code': 'A101','count':2},
 {'code': 'A102','count':4},
 {'code': 'A103','count':5},
 {'code': 'A103','count':10},
 {'code': 'A104','count':20},
 {'code': 'A104','count':0},
 {'code': 'A105','count':1},
 {'code': 'B101','count':20},
 {'code': 'B101','count':30}] 

Dict1 = 

{'A101': '10001',
 'A102': '10001',
 'A103': '10002',
 'A104': '10004',
 'A105': '10005',
 'B101': '10010'}

Output -- 

zip_count (zip and count) = [

'10001' = 7(3+4)
'10002' = 15(5+10)
'10004' = 20 (20+0) etc.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some sample(small) input and expected output?

Comment: Use ‘collections.Counter’ with ‘dict1.values()’

Comment: Your input and output is invalid. Please [edit] to fix it. This might seem like a small thing we could gloss over, but you need to make sure it's correct. See [mre] for details.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer:

```
List1 = [{'code': 'A101','count':2},
 {'code': 'A102','count':4},
 {'code': 'A103','count':5},
 {'code': 'A103','count':10},
 {'code': 'A104','count':20},
 {'code': 'A104','count':0},
 {'code': 'A105','count':1},
 {'code': 'B101','count':20},
 {'code': 'B101','count':30}]

Dict1 = {'A101': '10001',
 'A102': '10001',
 'A103': '10002',
 'A104': '10004',
 'A105': '10005',
 'B101': '10010'}

d = {}
for item in List1:
    d.setdefault(item['code'], 0)
    d[item['code']] += item['count']

# d now holds {'A101': 2, 'A102': 4, 'A103': 15, 'A104': 20, 'A105': 1, 'B101': 50}

rv = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    rv.setdefault(Dict1[k], 0)
    rv[Dict1[k]] += v

print(rv)
```

Prints:

```
{'10001': 6, '10002': 15, '10004': 20, '10005': 1, '10010': 50}
```

NOTE: the `dict.setdefault()` method is expliced [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

Comment: Andrej, apologies. I entered the dataset wrong, and just updated it. many thanks for ur solution despite that. can u pls help with the updated dataset (a list of dicts rather than sets). thanks again.